# std::align and std::aligned_storage for aligned allocation of memory blocks

Tags: c++, c++11, alignment, allocator

I'm trying to allocate a block of memory of size `size` which needs to be `Alignment` aligned where the size may not be defined at compile time. I know routines such as `_aligned_alloc`, `posix_memalign`, `_mm_alloc`, etc exist but I do not want to use them as they bring down code portability. 
**C++11** gives a routine `std::align` and also a class `std::aligned_storage` from which I can retrieve a POD type to allocate an element which will be aligned to my requirements. However my goal is to create an allocator which would allocate a block of memory of `size` size (not just a single element) which would be aligned. 
Is this possible using `std::align`? The reason I ask is since `std::align` moves the pointer, the class using that pointer will give the allocator a pointer to the moved address for deallocation which would be invalid. Is there a way to create an aligned_allocator this way?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Dynamic aligned memory allocation in C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973995/dynamic-aligned-memory-allocation-in-c11)?

Comment: Note that `std::align` isn't particularly portable… GCC doesn't implement it as of yet.

Comment: @jogojapan: No, I don't think so. This question particularly focuses on std::align and std::aligned_storage, not other solutions.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yes, I did notice that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** after clarifications from the OP, it appears the original answer is off-topic; for reference's sake it is kept at the end of this answer.

Actually, the answer is rather simple: you simply need to keep a pointer both to the storage block and to the first item.

This does not, actually, requires a stateful allocator (it could be possible even in C++03, albeit with a custom `std::align` routine). The trick is that the allocator is not required to only ask of the system exactly enough memory to store user data. It can perfectly ask a bit more for book-keeping purposes of its own.

So, here we go creating an aligned allocator; to keep it simple I'll focus on the allocation/deallocation routines.

```
template <typename T>
class aligned_allocator {
    // Allocates block of memory:
    // - (opt) padding
    // - offset: ptrdiff_t
    // - T * n: T
    // - (opt) padding
public:
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef size_t size_type;

    pointer allocate(size_type n);
    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n);

}; // class aligned_allocator
```

And now the allocation routine. Lots of memory fiddling, it's the heart of the allocator after all!

```
template <typename T>
auto aligned_allocator<T>::allocate(size_type n) -> pointer {
    size_type const alignment = std::max(alignof(ptrdiff_t), alignof(T));
    size_type const object_size = sizeof(ptrdiff_t) + sizeof(T)*n;
    size_type const buffer_size = object_size + alignment;

    // block is correctly aligned for `ptrdiff_t` because `std::malloc` returns
    // memory correctly aligned for all built-ins types.
    void* const block = std::malloc(buffer_size);

    if (block == nullptr) { throw std::bad_alloc{}; }

    // find the start of the body by suitably aligning memory,
    // note that we reserve sufficient space for the header beforehand
    void* storage = reinterpret_cast<char*>(block) + sizeof(ptrdiff_t);
    size_t shift = buffer_size;

    void* const body = std::align(alignment, object_size, storage, shift);

    // reverse track to find where the offset field starts
    char* const offset = reinterpret_cast<char*>(body) - sizeof(ptrdiff_t);

    // store the value of the offset (ie, the result of body - block)
    *reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t*>(offset) = sizeof(ptrdiff_t) + shift;

    // finally return the start of the body
    return reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t>(body);
} // aligned_allocator<T>::allocate
```

Fortunately the deallocation routine is much simpler, it just has to read the offset and apply it.

```
template <typename T>
void aligned_allocator<T>::deallocate(pointer p, size_type) {
    // find the offset field
    char const* header = reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) - sizeof(ptrdiff_t);

    // read its value
    ptrdiff_t const offset = *reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t*>(header);

    // apply it to find start of block
    void* const block = reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) - offset;

    // finally deallocate
    std::free(block);
} // aligned_allocator<T>::deallocate
```

The other routines need not be aware of the memory layout, so writing them is trivial.

---

Original answer:

```
template <typename T>
class Block {
public:
    Block(Block const&) = delete;
    Block& operator=(Block const&) = delete;

    explicit Block(size_t n);
    ~Block();

private:
    void* _storage;
    T* _begin;
    T* _end;
}; // class Block

template <typename T>
Block<T>::Block(size_t n) {
    size_t const object_size = n * sizeof(T);
    size_t const buffer_size = object_size + alignof(T);

    _storage = std::malloc(size);

    void* stock = _storage;
    size_t shift = buffer_size;
    std::align(alignof(T), object_size, stock, shift);

    _begin = _end = reinterpret_cast<T*>(stock);
} // Block<T>::Block

template <typename T>
Block<T>::~Block() {
    for (; _end != _begin; --_end) {
        (_end - 1)->~T();
    }

    std::free(_storage);
} // Block<T>::~Block
```

Comment: in `Block<T>::Block(size_t)`, you are assigning the same value to `_begin` and `_end`. Shouldn't `_end` be something like `_begin + dummy`?

Comment: Perhaps I miscommunicated in the question. The requirement is to create an allocator which would thus conform to the C++ standard allocator requirements. The way I see it, by making it a stateful allocator by storing both pointers could work as you stated. 
The problem revolves around creating an allocator with such requirements.

Comment: @TomKnapen: this is intentional, note that I do not initialize any `T` in there, I just reserve the underlying storage space.

Comment: @intull: Indeed I had not understood, I wrote the heart of what an aligned allocator would look like. Note that I assumed that the alignment could be derived from the type of `T`.

Comment: Yes! The trick you mentioned in your edit was what I was looking for! Great! I really appreciate it! Thank you.

Comment: For your aligned example the ```size_t shift = 0;``` will not work the way you think. The implementation of align is such that, should the _space_, or in terms of passed parameters **shift**, be less than the requested size minus difference in alignment it will return nullptr. This should be ```size_t shift;```.

link to an implementation: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/edd716b6b1caa1a5cb320a8cd7f626f30198e098/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/memory

Comment: @rtbaldwin: Indeed! Thank you for calling me on this, I have patched the answer to distinguish between `object_size` (the size of what we are attempting to fit in there) and `buffer_size` (the size of the memory block) and I now pass `buffer_size` as the 4th parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If it HAS TO BE a C++11 solution, then ignore this answer.

If not... I don't know if you already know this, but here is one option:

```
void * aligned_malloc( size_t size, size_t alignement )
{
    void * p = malloc( size + --alignement );
    void * p1 = (void*)( ( (size_t)p + alignement ) & ~alignement );

    ((char*)p1)[ -1 ] = (char)((char*)p1 - (char*)p);

    return p1;
}

void aligned_free( void * pMem )
{
    char * pDelete = (char*)pMem - ((char*)pMem)[ -1 ];
    free( pDelete );
}
```

Perhaps `malloc` and `free` are not 100% portable, but it's easy to handle such cases with preprocessor directives.