# Is it legal to cast float* to std::complex<float>*

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

[**N3797**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) **26.4 [complex.numbers]** says this about casting `std::complex<T>*` to `T*`

> 4 Moreover, if a is an expression of type `cv std::complex<T>*` and the expression `a[i]` is well-defined for an integer expression `i`, then:
>    - `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i]` shall designate the real part of `a[i]`, and
>    - `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i + 1]` shall designate the imaginary part of `a[i]`.

Does this (or some other wording of the standard) imply that I can `reinterpret_cast` the other way?  Can I do this:

```
    float * pf;
    std::complex<float>* pc = reinterpret_cast<std::complex<float>*>(pf);
    pc[i].real();
```

As n.m. pointed out below, I would have to make sure the alignment of `pf` is suitable for a `std::complex<float>`.  This can be assumed to be taken care of.

Comment: Alignment requiements for `complex<float>` may be stricter than that of `float`.

Comment: @n.m. Fair enough, as I understand, that can be fixed by `std::align` as per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973995/dynamic-aligned-memory-allocation-in-c11).

Comment: legal, yes `reinterpret_cast` basically just tells the compile to interpret a chunk of memory as whatever type. Safe... oh my no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that clause makes no such guarantee.

Now, in practice, the most common issue would be alignment: but even that may be rare.

The second problem would involve strict aliasing, where memory allocated as a `double` can be assumed by the compiler to not be modified by any operation involving pointers to other types (except `char`).  The above places a restricition going the other way (a `complex` allocated pointer may not assume thay `double*`s do not point to its data), but not in the direction you want.  Again this is relatively obscure, but a compiler could use this to reorder writes in your code.

It will, however, usually work.  More often if you align it, and your compiler does not use strict aliasing assumptions: even then it is undefined behaviour by the standard, however.

Comment: Accessing members of `std::complex<double>` only accesses the memory through a pointer to a `double`, so I don't see how strict aliasing is a problem.

Comment: @guygreer `std::complex` does not contain a pointer to `double` in any implementation I can imagine.  Strict aliasing means that `double* b = new double[2]; *b = 3.0; `(*(complex<double>*)(b)) = complex<double>(2); std::cout << *b;` can change the print statement to `std::cout << 3.0;` because the strict aliasing violation. @guygreer

Comment: There are some typos in the last comment -- I was supposed to cast to a complex pointer.  My point is that aliasing need only work on layout compatible types: the standard nearly, but not quite, guarantees layout compatibility between complex and twice as many `double`s in an array.  Note that this level of twistedness may not apply to any compiler you ever work with.

Comment: It is a shame there doesn't seem to be a way to obtain a reference or pointer to the underlying data.  Having a std::data compatible member function that returns a T* is useful for things such as simd operations on std::complex<float> and std::complex<double>.  Vectorizing std::complex basically requires using reinterpret_cast at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work the other way round. A `std::complex<float>` is two consecutive `float`'s in memory as proven by what the standard does allow you to do, but you have a pointer to a single float value and turn it into a pointer to a structure which should contain two floats. Even if you would have two floats, the standard doesn't guarantee it and it would therefore be illegal to `reinterpret_cast` to pointers in that direction.