# alignas keyword not respected

Tags: c++, c++11, alignas

I want to overalign my type on a cache boundary, so I used `alignas`:

```
struct alignas(64) W { };
```

This compiles fine. But then, to my surprise, when I try to allocate a bunch of `W`s, they're not 64-byte aligned but actually 16-byte aligned:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <unordered_map>

struct alignas(64) W { };

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> offset;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        auto w = new W;
        offset[(uintptr_t)w % 64]++;
    }   

    for (const auto& p : offset) {
        std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '\n';
    }   
}
```

Yields:

```
0 250
16 250
32 250
48 250
```

on several compiles (gcc 4.8.2, gcc 5.2.0, clang 3.7.1). What's up? I told it to align, why isn't it aligning?

Comment: ["It is implementation-defined whether over-aligned types are supported (\[basic.align\])."](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#1). See also [CWG issue 2130](http://wg21.link/cwg2130).

Comment: @T.C. That looks like it should be an answer.

Comment: @T.C. How do I know if an implementation supports it (apparently neither gcc nor clang do)

Comment: operator new is borken, the compiler knows the alignment requirement but has no way to tell the operator about it.  So this is pretty much guaranteed to go wrong.  It's your burden to work around it, something like aligned_alloc() or posix_memalign() or _aligned_malloc().

Comment: @HansPassant Is that only for `new`? If I create a `W` on the stack, will it be guaranteed 64-bytes aligned?

Comment: Yes, the compiler can control that, it picks stack offsets.

Comment: @HansPassant To add to that recommendation, you can probably create an `operator new` and `operator delete` inside `struct W` that call `aligned_alloc` and `aligned_free` internally without complicating the job for external clients

Comment: As a remark, I cannot reproduce using CLang 3.4.1 on a FreeBSD 10.1: your program correctly gives `0 1000`

Comment: Related proposal: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r1.html

Comment: It is interesting that here `alignof( W )` returns 64, i.e. the _requested alignment_ rather than the actual one, 16. (gcc 5.2.1)

Comment: @T.C. Do you have a link that doesn't require us to log in as part of "the WG21 ISO standards committee and its invited members"? Perhaps mercifully, most of us are neither of those things. :-)

Comment: @underscore_d Whoever operates wg21.link recently changed it to be useless to mere mortals (at least for CWG issues). /sigh http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2130

Comment: @T.C. Thanks! And now I remember: Apparently this is **resolved for C++17**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38060437/2757035 I don't know whether this will be considered a defect to be fixed retroactively in earlier Standards?

Answer (score 3):

This is answered nicely here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16510895

Basically: `new` (at least in its normal usage) only guarantees a constant maximum alignment (`alignof(std::max_align_t)`) for every call to `new`.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct in the sense that it explains the existing limitation, but I'd like to point out that things are about to get better.

As indicated by T.C. in the comments, this was a long-standing deficiency in the language. It [looks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38060437/2757035) like [the WG effort](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r1.html) to fix this has led to a resolution in C++17 (which has just attained feature-complete status). Thus, when compiling to that Standard, overalignment will finally be respected by dynamic allocation, by using the new `std::align_val_t` overloads of `new`. Thus solving Barry's problem!

Given the amount of new scaffolding required, I presume this won't be backported to earlier versions of the Standard, so the old *caveat* about their dynamic allocation only sufficing for types having fundamental alignment will presumably remain true.