# Writing C++ Destructor

Tags: c++, destructor

If I define a custom destructor, do I have to delete every variable manually?

Memory allocated by `malloc` should be `free`d in the destructor. How about the pointer to the memory allocated by `malloc`, and an `int`?
a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    uint32_t  x;
    uint32_t* ar_y;
    A(void);
    ~A(void);
};
#endif
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
A::A(void){
    x = 0;
    ar_y = (uint32_t*)(malloc(4));
}
A::~A(void){
    // free the memory allocated by malloc
    free(ar_y);
    //Is it ok to do nothing for int* y and int x?
}
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
int f(void){
    A objA;
    //cout << objA.x << endl;
    //Upon exiting the function
    //destructor of A is called.
}
int main(void){
    uint32_t i;
    // see if memory usage go crazy.
    for (i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) f();
}
```

Test result:

memory usage didn't rise crazily.

Comment: delete[] y would free the allocated memory for y

Comment: @Bafforasta were `new` used, that would be proper indeed.

Comment: @WhozCraig I was just wandering why he didn't

Comment: Always make your destructor virtual!

Comment: "Upon exiting the function destructor of A is called"... the same is true for the non-heap allocated variables inside the object, ie they get destroyed once they go out of scope.

Comment: @Kieveli What is the point of making the desctructor virtual when the class is not meant to be inherited from?

Comment: @Kieveli: There are times when you should, but that's definitely not an "always" rule.

Comment: If you must use dynamic memory, prefer new and delete to malloc and free. Prefer container classes whenever possible. If you have access to boost or C++11, prefer smart pointers to raw pointers. That way, memory management is done for you.

Comment: what is virtual? is int* y; y = new int[5]; delete[] y; the accepted way to declare new array? I am allocating alligned memory. so didn't use new, or vector.

Comment: And fyi, if you think you need raw pointers, [seriously think again](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything for `x`. You need to take care of deallocating memory pointed to by `ar_y`.

See [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) for more info on what you need to do when you allocate memory for member variables in a class.

Since you are in C++ land, prefer to use `new` and `delete` operators instead of using `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: If I have to allocate memory with 32 bit alignment in Linux ... what is the accepted way to do that in c++?

Comment: @rxu, See [Dynamic aligned memory allocation in C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973995/dynamic-aligned-memory-allocation-in-c11).

Comment: so, I guess that means. 1. write an abstraction layer. or 2. use pointer for allocation of aligned memory when performance is very important.

Comment: @rxu, that's also what I gathered from that post. I haven't personally dealt with this issue in my work.